# Foreach loop using smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

I need some hint regarding php syntax using smarty version 2.6.29..

The code looks like..

```
[-php-] 
// $array is assigned from another .php file
foreach($array as $arr){
    echo $arr;  
}
[-/php-]
```

Any help would be really helpful...

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
{foreach from=$array item=arr}
    <li>{$arr}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Source: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: yeah tried this but the application is using [-php-]  this syntax... instead of {php}...

Comment: Then replace every "{" for "[- " and "}" for "-]"

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with your syntax [-php-]):

```
[-php-]foreach from=$array item=arr[-/php-]
    [-php-]print_r($arr)[-/php-] // some code
[-php-]/foreach[-/php-]
```